# Getting specific items from iterating rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to find a way to pull all notes that are assigned to a course but only when necessary. I have a show page which shows all of the notes for a quiz.

course show.html.erb

```
<%= @course.name %>
<% @quiz.notes.each do |note| %>
    <%= link_to note.title, quiz_note_path(@quiz, note)  %><br/>
<% end %>
```

The above code works find except it pulls all of the notes and not the notes that are assigned to that course. How can I tell rails to only pull the note if note and course name are equal?

**update!**

In the note new.html.erb I have am using collection_select

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:course_ids, @quiz.courses, :id, :note_name, options = {:prompt => "Choose"}) %>
```

Comment: what does your data model look like?  from your example, it looks like quiz has many notes. and you are iterating over all the quiz notes.  if your course also has many notes, you should define it in your model so that you can go @course.notes.each.

Comment: @c0deNinja will that work even when using collection_select?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you don't have relationship between `course` and `quiz`.

A `course` has many `quizzes`, a `quiz` has many `notes`. You should setup your relationship this way, so it won't pull out unnecessary notes that are not related to the current `course`.

The trick here is to pull all notes inside a course by using `has_many :through`.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quizzes
  has_many :notes, :through => quizzes
end

class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :notes
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quiz
end

<%= @course.name %>
<% @course.notes.each do |note| %>
    <%= link_to note.title, quiz_note_path(note.quiz, note)  %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It does not give me an error but nothing shows. For Notes I am using collection_select field to grab the course names. Any reasons why it not displaying the notes under a course?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<%= @course.name %>
<% @quiz.notes.select { |n| n.title == @course.name }.each do |note| %>
  <%= link_to note.title, quiz_note_path(@quiz, note)  %><br/>
<% end %>
```

`Enumerable.select` evaluates the block and returns only the elements for which it was true.